# How to fix: no module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql-python

I want to connect my MYSQL DB to the python DB.I have installed pip mysql connector already.I opened pycharm and ran "import mysql.connector". Upon executing this code,I received 'no such module named mysql' error.

```
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: What environment are you using? Pycharm can handle mutiple environments. You can find them in the right bottom corner.
Did you check, you installed it correctly? Pycharm let's you install packages using it's GUI.
Also check if your configuration is set to the right interpreter (Run - Edit Confuguration)

Comment: I am using pycharm 3.7 and for that I have installed pip3.

Comment: Try using  PyCharm GUI for installing your packages. Do other imported modules work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you have tried so far, so I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but check your configuration.

Also, I'm not quite sure what *PyCharm 3.7* is? Did you mean *Python 3.7* and *PyCharm 2019*?
(For this answer, I'm using PyCharm Professional 2019 and Python 3.6

---

## Check your Settings

- First check your current interpreter. It can be found on the right side of your windows, bottom corner. 
  [image]
- Open `Interpreter Settings`. A window with a list will pop up, showing the currently install packages. Start typing the name of your package you are looking for. If it's not found, you must install it.
  [image]
- For installing, click on the small *plus*-Sign  on right of the list. The window called **Available Packages** will appear. Here search for your desired package. [image: Available Packages Window]
- Click on *Install Packages*
- Check your configuration: 
  Under *Run* -> *Edit Configurations* (or the Dropdown menu near the Run-Button) make sure you have selected the right **Python interpreter**. It must your previously selected interpreter.
  [image: Run-Config]

Comment: Great!! now it worked form me. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Glad that I helped you! Can you select it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when running the program in Pycharm, there is a file in venv >> scripts >> pyvenv.cfg  which had include-system-site-packages = false.  But once it is changed and set to true it worked for me.

version_info = 3.10.0.final.0
include-system-site-packages = true

Comment: This worked for me! Appreciate you sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that I had installed the `mysql` package but not `mysql-connector`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using correct python interpreter. Example: On Ubuntu operating system, for python2 there's `pip`, but for python3 there's `pip3`
using the wrong pip will make your packages unavailable for the other python version.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and for python 3 I am using pip3.

Answer (score 0):

Check your python install version.  If you have multiple versions be sure to use the correct pip version related.

```py
pip show mysql-connector-python

# or
 
pip3 show mysql-connector-python
```

If this returns:

> WARNING: Package(s) not found: mysql-connector-python

Then run

```py
pip install mysql-connector-python

# or

pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Rerun the first command and you should now see something like this:

```bash
>>> pip show mysql-connector-python
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.3.0
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email:
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: C:\Users\JayRizzo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```